# Unintentional split of the columns while writing to csv in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am **scraping** data from the web and write resulting content to csv. This is the code that I am using:

```
with open('main_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter="^")
    writer.writerow([patent_number, patent_type, grant_date, grant_country, app_number, app_country, \
                     application_date, for_num, for_date, for_ctry , int_classes, us_classes, title, n_of_claims, \
                     fields_of_search, n_of_drawings, inventor_names, inventor_address, \
                     assignee_names, assignee_address, attorn_names, primary_names, secondary_names])
```

The problem here is that for some reason, python starts to write content into new column after detecting `;` . In particular:

After `inventor_name = Korenaga; Nobushige` it keeps Korenaga in the first column and starts a new column with Nobushige. Same for the following inputs

```
assignee_address = Tokyo; JP
primary_names = Adams; Russell
secondary_names Nguyen; Hung Henry
```

How could I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with columns recognizing you can use [quotechar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for quoting columns.

```
with open("main_data.csv", "a", newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter="^", quotechar="\"")
    # some code
    pass
```

**Upd.**

From futher conversation we found that code works properly (code in question works too). Problem is in Excel, which recognize `;` as a delimiter and divides data into seperate columns.

Constructor of [writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) object allows you to pass `dialect` argument. Default value is `excel`. As we see in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel):

> The excel class defines the usual properties of an Excel-generated CSV file. It is registered with the dialect name 'excel'.

So, solution is very simple - delete all arguments from `csv.writer` except first.

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
```

As a resut we will get csv file compaitable with Excel.

Comment: You mena I should quote ; ?

Comment: @edyvedy13, I've checked code with `writer.writerow(["f;f;f;f", "s,s,s,s,s"])` and it wrote `f;f;f;f^s,s,s,s,s` in file.

Comment: Let me share the actual input

Comment: I edited the question by adding the problematic inputs

Comment: And again, `writer.writerow([assignee_address, primary_names, secondary_names])` writes into console `Tokyo; JP^Adams; Russell^Nguyen; Hung Henry`, which is proper output.

Comment: I get exact same results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192847/discussion-between-olvin-roght-and-edyvedy13).